# Airflow cannot import local module - false flag

Tags: python, airflow, pythonpath

I have a repo that has the below structure.

```
etl
--dags
--src
----foo
```

Everything currently works in terms of running the dags. However, when I go to the UI, I see "Broken DAG: [*path*] No module named 'foo'.

I am running the webserver and scheduler as service files on an ec2 instance.

I have tried updating my PYTHONPATH to have the /src/foo included. In all of my dag files I import as "import foo.utils.logging" which is one of the imports causing the issue.

Looking for any ideas or help! Thank you.

Comment: Maybe your question would get better chances of receiving answers if it contained a [mre].